Building APK won't work, probably doing something wrong with my gradle files in Flutter project
I am building a flutter app with Visual Code,  version 1 of the app worked fine,  including building and signing my APKs with Flutter build apk.
Then I introduced firebase and Firecore,  and after completion of the app... I cannot build my APK anymore.  I strongly suspect I am doing stuff wrong in my gradle files.  But I am just not clever enough to find out what.  Been searching for countless hours,  but no luck yet.
Hope you guys can help me out.
I tried adjust my gradle files multiple times,  no luck yet
I appreciate the help and explanations.
I will put my gradle files under the error
The latest error when I try to inspect the gradle with
gradle build --scan --warning-mode all
https://gradle.com/s/jt6ihjarbqzr4
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction > C
project level

buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.23' 

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.6'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
}

repositories {
    google() 
    mavenCentral() 
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app level
plugins {
  id 'com.android.application'
  id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  id 'kotlin-android'

}

android {
    namespace "com.berksport_app"
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0"))
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.1'
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore")
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.9.9'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
}


targetSdkVersion 33
Override your dev dependency:
dependency_overrides:
   firebase_core: ^2.4.1

Re-build your project:
flutter clean
flutter pub get

Another way to solve it:
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions

Thank me later
